# UIView IBOutlet not changing when change called from a different class

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel

I have an XIB with a UILabel to it. I have referenced the UILabel to a UIView class that I have created. I can change the label using `label.text = "hi"` when initializing the view. When I try and call a change from another class it doesn't change the UILabel on screen (but if I print `label.text` it shows as what I set it to). I cannot make the UILabel load the text when initializing as the text could be changed by the user at any time. (switchText() is called from a UITableCell)

**2nd class**

```
class Second {
    func switchText() {
        let first = First()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            first.label.text = "bye"
        }
    }
}
```

**1st class**

```
class First: UIView {
    let kCONTENT_XIB_NAME = "First"
    
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(kCONTENT_XIB_NAME, owner: self, options: nil)
        contentView.fixInView(self)
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Also, in my XIB I have my UIView hooked up to `File's Owner` and contentView inside my UIView class. My label outlet goes to file's owner and then to the UIView class where it is declared as label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not really changing the text on your `First()` class. What your `switchText()` function does is create another reference of the class named First and then set the text of the label for that new reference.

```
let first = First()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    first.label.text = "bye"
}
```

What you can do is make your `switchText()` function conform to a protocol then call it on your `First()` class through a delegate.

```
protocol SecondClassDelegate {
    func didSwitchText(editedText: String)
}

class Second {
    var delegate: SecondClassDelegate!

    func switchText() {
        delegate.didSwitchText("bye")
    }
}
```

Now you can add this to your `First()` class

```
class First: SecondClassDelegate {
    func didSwitchText(editedText: String) {
        label.text = editedText
    }
}
```

Just don't forget to set the delegate wherever you're setting your `Second()` class

```
let second = Second()
second.delegate = self
```

I suggest reading about this for a better understanding of delegates. https://www.appcoda.com/swift-delegate/

Comment: Could you please add an example of this?